# How to set a vagrant environment's date and time?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to set the date and time on a vagrant environment (e.g. to 29th of June).

I used the following Vagrantfile to achieve this.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"  

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo date -s '2022-06-29 12:34:56'", run: "always"

end
```

When I run `vagrant up` I see

> [...]
> default: Running: inline script
> default: Wed Jun 29 12:34:56 UTC 2022

but then when I connect with ssh and execute `date` the current date is printed.

When I try to change the time manually via ssh with `sudo date -s '2022-06-29 12:34:56'` and execute `date` I see the changed date.
But If I exit and get back in, I again see the current date and time.

**How can I permanently change the date and time on an environment, or at least set it when the environment starts?**

NOTE: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/539881/431826) describes how to do this on virtualbox-level:

```bash
VBoxManage setextradata "The VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1

# Milliseconds to shift to in the past
VBoxManage modifyvm "The VM name" --biossystemtimeoffset -50000000
```

I tested the above and it works and obviously the milliseconds can be calculated knowing the current date and the date to which we want to go to. But again the above is not an automatic solution via Vagrant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because vagrant and virtualbox questions are off topic here as stated in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a partial virtualbox-specific solution using triggers:

```
  config.vm.define "mymachine" do |mymachine|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"  
 
    mymachine.trigger.before :up do |trigger|
      trigger.info = "changing time"
      trigger.ruby do |env,machine|
        puts `VBoxManage setextradata #{machine.id} "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1`
        puts `VBoxManage modifyvm #{machine.id} --biossystemtimeoffset -150000000`
      end
    end
  end
```

I guess what is left is to calculate the milliseconds for shifting to the desired date based on current vm's date.